# Show that two metrics are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $d_*$ be the following metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
>
> $d_*((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}+\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}$

I need to prove that it is equivalent to the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I can easily get the lower bound, but I can't seem a way to find a coefficient for the upper bound.

Comment: Equivalent in which sense? Clearly $d_*(A,B)=AO+OB$ can be arbitrarily larger than $d_2(A,B)=AB$.

Comment: It's unclear what the four variables $x_1$, $y_1$, $x_2$, $y_2$ mean.

Comment: I need to show that $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_∗)$ is a complete metric space, so I thought that seeing that it is equivalent to the usual metric would be a good approach.

Comment: $d_*$ isn't a metric is it?  The distance from a point to itself isn't $0$, in general.

Comment: This can't possibly be a metric. $d((1,1),(1,1)) = 2 \sqrt{2}$. It should be zero if a metric.

Comment: They are not equivalent, even if we correct it to include $d(x,y)=0$ when $x=y$. See post-office metric.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $d^\ast$ has to be complemented with the trivial but necessary clause that $d^\ast((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=0$ when $ x_1=y_1 \land x_2=y_2$. So I’ll assume that, which does make it a valid metric.

$\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is a discrete open subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ in this metric. In the usual metric there are no open discrete subspaces at all. Totally different topology so not equivalent. Or $\{(1,1)\}$ is clopen so $(\Bbb R^2, d^\ast)$ is not connected etc.